# Are constructors inherited in python

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, python-2.5

I'm working on one of the MIT 6.00 OCW problem sets, and I have the following code...

```
class Trigger(object):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        """
        Returns True if an alert should be generated
        for the given news item, or False otherwise.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError

# Whole Word Triggers
# Problems 2-5

# WordTrigger

class WordTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word

    def is_word_in(self, text):
        word = self.word.lower()
        text = text.lower()

        #Remove punc and split text
        for ch in string.punctuation:
            text = text.replace(ch, ' ')
        splitText = text.split(' ')

        #Check if word is in text
        return word in splitText


# TitleTrigger

class TitleTrigger(WordTrigger):
##    def __init__(self, word):
##        self.word = word

    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.is_word_in(story.get_title())
```

I originally didn't comment out the constructor in `TitleTrigger()` but when I ran the provided test script it threw an error when the test utility tried to call my `TitleTrigger()` class. I couldn't figure out what was wrong so I peaked at the solution code and they had commented out the constructor, so that's what I did and it worked fine. This left me with three questions...

1. Am I correct in thinking that subclasses will automatically inherit the constructor of their super-class if it's not defined in the subclass? It seems like that's what's happening when I comment this out.
2. The constructor I used in `TitleTrigger()` is an exact duplicate of the constructor in its super-class `WordTrigger()`, so why would it matter whether I defined it in the subclass or allowed the subclass to inherit it?
3. I have two other subclasses of `WordTrigger()` which are identical to `TitleTrigger()` except one looks for a word in the subject of a story and the other looks in summary. These two pass the tests just fine with their own constructors, which seems really bizarre.

I can include the testing code if needed, though if the issue is just a quirk in how that code tests my classes I don't really need to know what that quirk is. What I'd really like to know for sure for future cases is whether subclasses automatically inherit their super-classes constructors if they (the subclasses) don't define their own, kind of like how they inherit other methods from the super-class.

Comment: Yes, all classes inherit all methods of their superclass, including `__init__`.  As for why you got your error, it's hard to say anything about that because you didn't show what the error was.

Comment: "when I ran the provided test script it threw an error" - perhaps the test utility is specifically looking for whether you overwrote __init__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correct in thinking that subclasses will automatically inherit
>   the constructor of their super-class if it's not defined in the
>   subclass?

Yes. The concern in Java that prevents this from happening is overloading (i.e. everyone inherits from `Object`, so everyone would end up with a nullary constructor). Not an issue in Python, so we get to inherit constructors.

> The constructor I used in TitleTrigger() is an exact duplicate of the
>   constructor in its super-class WordTrigger(), so why would it matter
>   whether I defined it in the subclass or allowed the subclass to
>   inherit it?

It shouldn't (except for the sake of reducing code duplication), unless I'm missing something.

> These two pass the tests just fine with their own constructors, which
>   seems really bizarre.

Yes it is. I can't guess what's wrong without seeing more code/errors. Also, it seems like overkill to use classes here -- a function would do just fine. Not Java, so we don't need to wrap everything in useless layers of OO.

Comment: `private X () {}` - "nullary constructor", have we access in a subclass? Anyway, more so - constructors in Java are *not* virtual and are *not* inherited, overloaded or not. Every constructor in Java class *must* (explicitly or implicitly) invoke a super constructor of the base type.

Comment: Thanks, this helped!!

As for using classes, it's part of the problem set, just a way to start working with classes and learn how they operate.